# How to share common resources between many webapplications?

Tags: java, image, resources, share

I have 4 web applications. But images, css, javascripts are the same.
When I do changes in one project after I need propagate changes to all projects.
What the best way - create common jar only with resoures or use something similar to links in SVN or else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the maven resources plugin, you can specify a [copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) goal that will copy the common resources into the specified projects prior to building the war files.

I've also seen the use of a common directory that is links (`ln -s`) during the build. This avoids the space and time load of creating physical copies of the resources.

Comment: yes, they are quite flexible and will allow for cleaner separation between the common resources and the projects that use them. Multimodule projects will give you a similar loose coupling between your various resources. [Here's](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) a good comparison between the two. I would say that in general it depends on how closely your web applications are related and whether they will ever be used as part of another set of web applications. If not, then the resources plugin will probably be faster to work with

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement and got exactly what I needed using **Bower** and a small **Perl script**.

The problem with doing a simple copy of files across your shared projects is if for any reason in the future you need one of your projects to temporarily have a slightly modified version, you will essentially either break your project or your deploy routine. It's a much cleaner way to manage shared resources across projects by placing them in their own version controlled repository so each project can refer to a particular version either "latest" or "1.0.0" etc... now the solution:

**[Bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower)** is a package manager which can, among other things, help manage retrieval/dependencies of git repositories. You can fetch git repositories from urls or even local paths on a drive. So all the files that need to be shared across projects I place them in their own individual git repository. Bower can then fetch a particular version of the shared content. The only problem is that bower copies them all in one particular sub-directory which is not always ideal.

**Script([bower-redeployer](https://github.com/maximerassi/bower-redeployer))** so then I use this perl script to deploy the fetched shared resources to the right location in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions...

- Put them in a common jar file
- Put them on shared URL(s)

Comment: It seems not easy to put resources like images, html pages, css, javascripts in common jar file. They should be in war file.

Comment: put on shared URL also doesn't seem a good solution - it needs remake many applications.

Comment: It may mean changes to applications, yes.  But that doesn't mean it's not a good way share resources between applications.  Also means you can dynamically change them if you need.  :)

Comment: Im late to the party, but shared URL's also will optimize borwser cacheing across web modules.

Answer (score 1):

(Promoting [user710818's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445150/how-to-share-common-resources-between-many-webapplications#comment11945957_9445235) to an answer)

Consider using the Maven WAR plugin's overlay feature as described in the following links.  From the first link,

> Overlays are used to share common resources across multiple web applications. The dependencies of a WAR project are collected in WEB-INF/lib, except for WAR artifacts which are overlayed on the WAR project itself.

1. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html
2. http://java.dzone.com/articles/mavens-war-overlay-what-are
3. http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-overlays